# When using MVVM on Android, should each Activity have one (and only one) ViewModel?

Tags: android, mvvm

On [MVVM pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx), the ViewModel contains business logic and notifies the View when it needs to be updated. It is also notified by the view about user events.

As I understood it, each Model should have an associated ViewModel. So, if we have the following models:

- User
- Account

We would have the following ViewModels:

- UserViewModel
- AccountViewModel

However, all examples I find about data binding with MVVM, use a single ViewModel for a layout. And recently, Google has introduced the [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html) class within [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html). This leads me to believe an Activity would have a single ViewModel that would connect to all related Models:

User / Account  --> ActivityViewModel

This gets even more complicated if we think of a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html). Each adapter item could be a ViewModel itself, so an Activity with a RecyclerView would have multiple ViewModels within the list and plus a master one for the remaining view contents (assuming they require information from a ViewModel). For instance:

[image]

In this example, we have a list of Account ViewModels and one UserViewModel. How would this be embedded into a single ActivityViewModel?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You should have one ViewModel per View (Activity, Fragment or Custom View), with multiple LiveData, one for each logical unit. In the image one logical unit would be the user data, another logical unit would be the settings data, so you would have two LiveData exposed in the ViewModel.

[image: View with multiple LiveData]

These concepts can also be visible in the recommended app architecture google presented in the last Google I/O, where an Activity/Fragment has 1 ViewModel with multiple LiveData:

[image]

Comment: If you are wondering what if we having multiple views which maybe either activities or fragments should I use 1 ViewModel per activity or fragment? Answer would be Yes, simply because it would help your code in maintenance with slight chance of code duplication. IMO code duplication is always better than maintaining a huge single file code base. You can have a parent ViewModel on top of those small view models to have better control when accessing the repo. For more help, refer this answer which is explained beautifully. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/308592/386895

Comment: Is this still the recommended approach using compose? I have raised a separate question  https://stackoverflow.com/q/73553518/15597975

Answer (score 19):

Google suggests that you use 1 `ViewModel` per `View` (i.e., `Activity` or `Fragment`) (see https://youtu.be/Ts-uxYiBEQ8?t=8m40s), and then inside each `ViewModel` you can have more than 1 type of Model. However, the MVVM principle is to have only 1 Model type per `ViewModel`, so Google's presentation contradicts that :/. I guess you'll have to decide what approach works better for your app.

About the list example you mentioned, that is not how you'd do it, for lists you'd use the [paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html). You can see details on how to use this at the end of the video I linked above.

Comment: They don't mention anything about 1 `ViewModel` per `View`.

Answer (score 9):

One view model is standard. However, even google suggests that you may have more than one view model. That comes quite convenient when you mitgrate a phone app towards a tablet app. When you combind more than one phone views on a single tab view, then it is convenient re-using the models.

If you have the SOLID principles in mind when coding, then the S (single responsibitly of a class) may cause you to use more than one view model.

However, one per view is pretty much standard and you shold have reasons, as metioned above, to use more than one.

Comment: I have one activity showing up multiple fragments. this activity has one viewmodel that it's only purpose is to request data to a server  and those request are called by the fragments. Should I split my viewModel by fragment? Also I create my LiveData objets in the viewModel and the fragments observes this LiveData to paint the view. It is correct?  I am using viewmodel to try to learn architecture components but I don't know if I am using it in a good way. Thanks.

Comment: @PabloR. that is hard to say from a distance, whether you apply the pattern in a smart way. I think it is fair, in simple cases, to use one view model and share it amongst all fragments. When it is a bit more complicated, especially when several different serices are called for different fragments, then I would provide one VM for each fragment. The VM can then share a use case class (or remote source class) which will provide the service calls to the view models.

Comment: Thanks @Herman. In my case the services calls are different from any fragment. I have 2 Activities (Login and Main) LoginViewModel calls to 2 different API and MainViewModel has only one. So if it doen's get more complicated I will keep it like this.

Comment: Well, when the calls are different then there is no advantage in sharing one commen VM. If you really whant to have all calls together in one backend facade or so, then to that separately and let every view model call its method of that backend facade. Make the facade injectable into the view model and you have perfectly testable view models.

Answer (score 1):

What is the relationship between Users and Accounts? If these are two separate, unrelated models, then they should each have their own views and view models. Remember the single responsibility principle: each module should be responsible for only a single part of your logic. That way, any changes to your domain logic or models will only affect that part, and that part only.

Comment: After more consideration I agree that each model should get its own ViewModel. However, I still find it hard to have one View per Model. The activity may want to present parts of multiple models and we could have a single view connected with multiple ViewModels.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is okay to have 1 View with multiple ViewModels.

View - answers the "how", how should a UI rendered. But it should never answers the "when".

ViewModel - answers the "when", it's the presentation logic and tells when should the data be rendered in View but ViewModel should never have reference to any View. Instead View observes and listen on ViewModels.

Model - answers the "where", it's the business logic which handles data (local/remote) request. Where to get data and where to store.

As long as ViewModel do not have any reference of View, it should be okay since we can have a situation with Fragment that has its own `ViewModel` and another `ViewModel` which comes from its host Activity. We call this concept [Shared ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#host-activity) which uses `by activityViewModels()` that can be use by the Fragments to communicate with each other when hosted under the same Activity.

You will have a Fragment that has 1 ViewModel own by the fragment itself and 1 ViewModel own by the host Activity.