# Is it ok to have different ViewModels for each Composable on a single screen in Android?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

In a previous StackOverflow question it was recommended that each `Activity` should have a single `ViewModel`. If there are different 'sections' on the screen which require different model data, then this should be handled with multiple `LiveData` in single `ViewModel`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482736/15597975

With [Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose?gclid=Cj0KCQjwjbyYBhCdARIsAArC6LLrL9cqyCDTM14IBIeNl_v2l494w0SLKhG6PD4qWMolFPLGYaRqh1UaAmfHEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) now released, is it ok to have different ViewModels for different 'sections' on the screen i.e. each section is represented as a different `composable` and each composable has it's own `ViewModel` with own odel `LiveData`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We recommend having 1 `ViewModel` per Screen and then passing down the state from there. This makes Composables more reusable and testable because your Composables aren't tied to a particular ViewModel, just the state they require.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyScreen(viewModel: ViewModel) {
   Column {
      TopPart(viewModel.topState)
      BottomPart(viewModel.bottomState)
   }
}

@Composable
fun TopPart(topState: TopState) {}

@Composable
fun BottomPart(bottomState: BottomState) {}
```

Comment: I was thinking about this and how it would work if you are using `collectAsState()` inside `MySreen`. Wouldn't it inefficiently cause recomposition twice on both `TopPart` and `BottomPart`, even when only when one of the states were updated?

Comment: They should just be skipped if nothing has changed

Comment: But the `MyScreen` composable would re-draw all the nodes in `Columm{}` even if only one of the states changed? i.e. it would redraw one node with the new (updated) state and the other node with the same (stale) state, which seems inefficient. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: No, Compose will skip recomposing composables when their state hasn't changed.